# Do I need to set a childs parent?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

I am having an issue where the Domain (child) is not getting the Business (parents) id. I have the business created and the domain but the domain does not have the business_id. Below is what I was doing originally. I then made a test path that I called which gave the same behavior unless I used the `setBusiness` method of the `domain`. Is this the expectation? Do I need to loop over the domains that are passed from a client and set the business?

**Test**

```
public void test() {
    Business b = new Business();
    b.setName("Test Test");
    Domain d1 = new Domain();
    d1.setName("Domain 1");
    d1.setBusiness(b);
    em.persist(b);
    em.flush();
}
```

**Code**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Business")
public class Business {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="business", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Domain> domains = new ArrayList<>();
    //...getters and setters
}
```

-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Domain")
public class Domain {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "business_id", nullable = false)
    private Business business;
    //...getters and setters
}
```

I was calling a rest service using the below JSON which then persisted the business.

```
{
    "name": "Business Test ",
    "domains": [{"name": "test domain"}]
}


@Path("business")
public class BusinesResouce {

    @EJB
    BusinessService service;

    @Path("create")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void create(Business entity) {
        service.persist(entity);
    }
    //other paths
}
```

-

```
@Stateless
public class BusinessService {
    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "edc";
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME)
    private EntityManager em;

    public void persist(Business entity) {
        em.persist(entity);
        //Do I really need to loop entity.getDomains and setBusiness?
        em.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes. The side of a relationship that 'owns' the foreign key must be set. Realistically you should be setting both sides to keep them in synch.

Comment: @Chris Oh good it's not a bad config. Can you expand on the setting both? I thought that's the point of the annotations to keep them in sync.

Comment: They are just java objects, so if you set one side, you must set the other.   Put another way, if one relation is null and the other is set, which is correct?  The mapped by states that the 'other' side controls the foreign key, so that owning relationship is used and must be set to what you want in the DB at a minimum, but there are many posts about why you should be setting both sides on your objects to keep them in synch with what you are putting in the database.

Comment: @Chris is this just saying that in the persist method I should be doing `entity.setDomains(domains)`? I can dig it. This is my first project from scratch with JPA. I am used to this stuff already being set up.